# How to repeat the cumsum for previous values in a Pandas Series, when the count group is restarted?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series that represents a group count.

How to create a new series with the maximum values from the series up to alter the count group?

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
s_count = pd.Series([1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4])
```

Desired:

```
s_max_count_group = pd.Series([3,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4])
```

Print result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'counts': s_count,
    'expected': s_max_count_group
})
print(df)
```

Display:

```
   counts  expected
0        1         3
1        2         3
2        3         3
3        1         5
4        2         5
5        3         5
6        4         5
7        5         5
8        1         4
9        2         4
10       3         4
11       4         4
```

- I looked for similar questions, tested some answers, so i'm trying to use `fill`, `cumsum`, `diff` and `mask` methods, but no success up to now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can identify the individual groups by comparing the count group with `1` followed by `cumsum`, then group the given series on these indentified groups and transform using `max`

```
s_count.groupby(s_count.eq(1).cumsum()).transform('max')
```

---

```
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     5
4     5
5     5
6     5
7     5
8     4
9     4
10    4
11    4
dtype: int64
```